# Any performance difference to identical spec of LFF disks vs SFF disks?

Tags: hardware, performance, hard-drive

Example:

HP 146GB LFF 6G SAS 15k
vs
HP 146GB SFF 6G SAS 15K

bit-size, cache, interface speed and rpms are the same, physical size is obviously different -- what about actual real life tested performance? Anybody with practical experience or benchmarks for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the platter sizes are different, then yes. In that case, average seek latency will be lower on the smaller spindle.

Don't assume that these drives have different platter sizes, though. Some LFF drives use SFF-sized platters for the increased performance they offer.

Comment: +1 The smaller platters yield about 20-30% more performance in typical applications; though it's not uncommon for the 15K drives to be 2.5" platters regardless of form factor.